# Is it possible to define what happens prior to vagrant destroy?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I have a [Vagrantfile](https://gist.github.com/seagoj/6616259) that clones the required cookbook repos on `vagrant up`. The problem is, it also does this on `vagrant destroy`. Is there a way to define 'pre-construction' and 'pre-destruction' commands or does the Vagrantfile just get run in totality each time vagrant is invoked regardless of the parameters?

Comment: check out this little plugin I've written, maybe it could fit your needs: https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about a destroy hook, but you can detect first time and post-destoy actions in the Vagrantfile by checking the existence of the machine ID:

```
File.exists?(".vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id")
```

I use this to drop in the public key for the machine, which allows me to setup a secure SSH key automatically:

```
if ! File.exists?(".vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id")
    # Then this machine is brannd new.
    system "cp #{KEYS_DIR}/workstation.pub #{OUR_DIR}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing your own cookbook dependency manager I strongly suggest using [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) or [librarian](https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian-chef). Both have plugins for Vagrant which already have the functionality you're looking for.

I started using librarian (simpler, focuses on doing one thing well), but have switched to Berkshelf (it's like adding extra blades to my knife command).