# Access machine ID from trigger

Tags: ruby, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I want a trigger (via the [`vagrant-triggers` plugin](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers)) to be active only for the Virtualbox provider. In this case, a second virtual disk should be removed from the machine configuration. Below is an excerpt of my `Vagrantfile`:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb, override|
    # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1536"]

    override.trigger.after :halt, :append_to_path => ENV["VBOX_INSTALL_PATH"] do
      run "VBoxManage storageattach " +
        File.read(".vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id") +
        " --storagectl SATA --port 1 --medium none"
    end
  end
end
```

In the example above, I can use `:id` to refer to the machine ID when setting the memory size; but I have only found an adventurous hack in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20860087/946850) to get hold of the machine ID in the `after` trigger.

It seems I can only use `run` methods in a trigger definition, calling `customize` doesn't work. Is there a better way to access the machine ID in a trigger?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [ticket solution](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers/issues/29), you can use `@machine.id`. An example:

```
config.trigger.after :halt do
  info "Machine ID: #{@machine.id}"
end
```

Comment: Now that triggers is integrated into Vagrant proper, it doesn't appear this works anymore. Is there an updated method for accessing the ID programmatically without just examining the file system to find out after the fact what it is? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37622689/3794873 for a method of doing the latter.