# Is it possible to determine the id of vagrant vm in the vagrantfile?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I read that it's possible to create a file with the name "id" and with the written id inside and put it into .vagrant/... directory. But is it also possible to determine the id in the vagrantfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vagrantfile is a ruby script you can always read the id file from Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  p "read uuid " + File.read(".vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/index_uuid")
  p "read id " + File.read(".vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id")
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to determine the id before the vm is created?

Comment: not really, the id is set from the provider (in your case VirtualBox) but vagrant will not know about it and will get the value from the VM provider

Comment: With the new "Triggers" capability, you can use this in a post "up" scenario quite nicely, though in the initial `vagrant up` this file might not exist so you should check whether it is present first before relying on it.